# What do Eagle Owls symbolize in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter, symbols

The Malfoys have an Eagle Owl, and one is used to communicate between Voldemort and Crouch Jr. I really don't think it's the same owl, as the Malfoys were unlikely to be in contact with Voldemort at that point (although I'm sure Lucius knew something was up). Did Crouch Jr. own the owl and keep it at Hogwarts or was it Voldemort's? Or is there a chance it was indeed the Malfoys' owl?

Is there anything significant about it being an Eagle Owls? Have they, in our history, been associated with evil?

Comment: the owls generally have a mixed image in various culture around the world. To the ancient maya - inca and red indians the owl were a harbinger of ill omen. The ancient persians also had a negative image of owls. But in hindu scriptures, owl is of high esteem and depicted as mount of hindu goddess of wealth. In ancient greek culture owl was symbol of Athena. In old english culture owls were symbol of wisdom. So no hard feeling about owls, let alone eagle-owls in particular. It is a personal choice on part of the author.

Comment: Duplicate of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80206/why-was-harry-potter-flying-on-an-eagle-owl-in-his-dream-in-goblet-of-fire?

Comment: @Richard - I am inclined to agree.

Answer (score 1):

I'd imagine that it would serve dual purposes.

1. It's not native the the UK and therefore would be more expensive, this would act as a status symbol - very important to the malfoys and other pure bloods.
2. It's a large owl, therefore would be able to carry larger loads/packets/parcels.

*Can't find any references to eagle owls being evil though*

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurasian_eagle-owl