# Is there an explanation for this change in perspective?

Tags: harry-potter

In the Goblet of Fire, when Harry has his dream-like visions of Voldemort, the visions take an outside perspective, in which Harry is just an observer of what is going on. For instance:

> Harry tried to recall what he had been dreaming about before he had awoken. It had seemed so real.... There had been two people he knew and hone he didn't.... He concentrated hard, frowning, trying to remember....
>
> ...
>
> He closed his eyes tightly and tried to remember what Voldemort had looked like, but it was impossible.... All Harry knew was that at the moment when Voldemort's chair had swung around, and he, Harry, had seen what was sitting in it, he had felt a spasm of horror, which had awoken him... or had that been the pain in his scar?
>
> And who had the old man been? For there had definitely been an old man; Harry had watched him fall to the ground...
>
> **Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire - US Paperback - Page 17**

As the passage shows, Harry does not see this from Voldemort's perspective, but rather as he himself were actually in the room at the time. Again, later in the book, when Harry has his vision of Voldemort torturing Wormtail, Harry saw himself riding an owl which delivered a message to Voldemort, not from Voldemort's perspective.

However, in Order of the Phoenix, Harry's visions come from the perspective of Voldemort. When Nagini attacks Mr. Weasly, Harry thought that he was the snake, and was personally responsible for the attack. It is later explained that Harry saw the scene from this perspective because it was likely that Voldemort was possessing Nagini at the time, and as Voldemort's mind was with the snake, so was Harry's. Again, later on, we see that when Voldemort plants the image of himself torturing Sirius, in an effort to lure Harry to the Ministry of Magic, Harry's vision takes the perspective as seen from Voldemort.

So why is it that after Voldemort regains a proper body, does Harry's visions of Voldemort change perspective? Is there any canonical explanation for this change?

Comment: it's probably that Voldemort had a full body inb Order of the Phoenix

Comment: I think that everyone can agree that the biggest difference between the visions in OOTP and GoF is the fact that in OOTP Voldemort has a proper body. However, he does have a body in GoF (weak and frail as it may be), so it isn't like he's a spirit, all-encompassing the rooms where the visions take place.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68438/why-are-harrys-gof-dreams-in-the-third-person?rq=1 ?